# multicast windows 2008 r2 multicast

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, multicast

Has anyone seem a problem with reading multicast on a Windows server 2008 R2 machine?
We're running it on a Dell server PER710 using Xeon CPU's x5678 @ 3.60 GHz with a 64-bit OS.
Using wireshark I see that when the router/switch sends out a general request every 125 seconds, the server doesn't always re-request for all the groups it's currently joined to.
If there are no other recipients on the same lan joined to the same groups, I would think the server would need to always re-request for the full set of multicast groups it's joined.

Is this a bug in Windows? Has it been fixed on some firmware upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's another host in the same network that is also a member of some of the same groups, it may have already responded, in which case hosts with longer timers suppress the response. See [RFC 2236](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2236.txt).

Comment: I am  fairly certain that is no the case. However, if that was the case then wouldn't I still continue to see multicast data, even thought the host in question didn't respond to the general query from switch/router?

Comment: @AlKurlansky I guess so, if you are sniffing in the right place.